# idiomatic selection sort in clojure

Tags: clojure

I was trying to implement selection sort O(n2) in clojure. Yes the underlying sort uses the very efficient java's array sort. However this is a learning exercise.

The code below works, however I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way of rewriting it, as the below seems clunky -

```
(defn mins [coll]
  (reduce (fn[[min-coll rest-coll] val]
            (case (compare val (first min-coll))
              -1 [[val] (apply conj rest-coll min-coll)]
              0 [(conj min-coll val) rest-coll]
              1 [min-coll (conj rest-coll val)]))
          [[(first coll)] []]
          (rest coll)))

;; (mins [3 1 1 2]) => [[1 1] [3 2]]

(defn selection-sort [coll]
  (loop [[sorted coll] [[] coll]]
    (let [[s c] (mins coll)]
      (if-not (seq coll)
        sorted
        (recur [(concat sorted s) c])))))

(selection-sort [3 1 1 2 5 7 8 8 4 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional solution could be:

```
(defn selection-sort
  [input]
  (let [ixs (vec (range (count input)))
        min-key-from (fn [acc ix] (apply min-key acc (subvec ixs ix)))
        swap (fn [coll i j] (assoc coll i (coll j) j (coll i)))]
    (reduce
     (fn [acc ix] (swap acc ix (min-key-from acc ix))) input ixs)))
```

Comment: Alex I tried running it and it errors out. Did u get it work ?

Comment: Are you calling it on an argument vector or seq? If you want it to work with seqs unfortunately because of the subvec call the input needs to be transformed into a very first

Comment: Swap instead of subvec sorry*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
(defn remove-first [coll e]
  (if-let [pos (and (seq coll) (.indexOf coll e))]
      (vec (concat 
            (subvec coll 0 pos) 
            (subvec coll (inc pos))))
      coll))

(defn best [coll f]
  (reduce f
          (first coll)
          (rest coll)))

(defn select-sort 
  ([coll] (select-sort coll min))
  ([coll fmin]
   (loop [sorted (transient []) c (vec coll)]
     (if (seq c)
       (let [n (best c fmin)]
         (recur (conj! sorted n) (remove-first c n)))
       (persistent! sorted)))))

 => (select-sort [3 5 2])
 => [2 3 5]

 => (select-sort [3 5 2] max)
 => [5 3 2]
```